# Xamarin Firebase Chatapp Show Last Item in ListView

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

i try to create chat app with firebase. Everythings is done, but i just have one problem. Problem is i cant show coming or send new messages in listview. Message can be added listview but client should scroll manually to see new messages.

my problem is i cant use `_lstchat.ScrollTo()`, because i cant find value latest item in listview.

i try to use one more way;

i rotate my listview 180 and i can get  good view but i cant sort my listview items or i cant add new item top on firebase database.

please help me i cant find a way.

This is my subchat code:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Model.Chat>> subChat(string _roomKEY)
{
    var toUpdatePerson = (await fBclient
          .Child("ChatApp")
          .OnceAsync<Model.Room>()).Where(a => a.Object.Name == _roomKEY).FirstOrDefault();

    var data = fBclient.Child("ChatApp").Child(toUpdatePerson.Key).Child("Message")
                     .OrderByPriority()
                    .AsObservable<Model.Chat>()
                   .AsObservableCollection<Model.Chat>();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: after you add an item to the `ItemsSource`, you then pass that same item to `ScrollTo()`

Comment: @Jason can you add a small example?

Comment: `MyMessagesCollection.Add(newMessage);  _lstchat.ScrollTo(newMessage);`

Comment: thank you but this is realtime database my i dont add new data listview. I just only send database value and listview automatically showing subscrabed database values @Jason

Comment: that's why you need to post the relevant code in your question, otherwise we have to make assumptions about how your code works.  In this case, use `FirstOrDefault()` or `LastOrDefault` to get the first or last item in the list

Comment: i aded my subChat method can you check?

Comment: I just explained how to get the first/last item in the list.

Comment: i dont use list :D

Comment: it applies to any `IEnumerable`

Comment: im sorry but i dont know how to add LasatOrDefault. This is my binding;

_lstChat.BindingContext = await db.subChat(data.Name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FirstOrDefault()` or `LastOrDefault()` to get the first or last item in the list

```
var newdata = await db.subChat(data.Name);
var first = newdata.FirstOrDefault();
_lstChat.BindingContext = newdata;

_lstChat.ScrollTo(first);
```

Comment: it didnt work :(

Comment: i try to get count newdata with newdata.Count().ToString() return 0

Comment: then that is a problem in your `subChat` method you need to figure out

Comment: yes you right. Actually _lstChat.BindingContext = newdata; this is work i can see all values in listview but i cant use newdata.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Why not?  Are you getting an error or exception?  You need to provide specific information, not vague descriptions, if you expect us to help you.

Comment: hi again @jason i thank you and i have one more question for you everthing is working but i cant use scrollto method for income message because i dont have trigger event for income message. Do you have any idea for income message scrollto ?

Comment: that sounds like a new Firebase specific question